# Connecting with PostgreSQL in Jupyter Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have question I need to connect with postgresql in python but I have hostname, database name, password and port. I saw that I can use:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="",database="", user="", password="", port="5432")
```

but I don't have host and I don't know how to get it. I'm not exactly administrator of this database, I use database in other programm - Knime Analytics Platform and in this program I use hostname to connect with database.

Comment: Host Name  – is the server name or IP address on which PostgreSQL is running. if you are running on localhost, then you can use localhost, or it’s IP i.e., 127.0.0.0 - https://pynative.com/python-postgresql-tutorial/

Comment: `hostname = host`

Answer (score 0):

Answering as I can't comment yet: What is the Postgres URL that you have? The url should give you all the details such as name, host, pw, user and port. Here are two examples that explain the URLs themselves: the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) and a [tutorial from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html). It might be a typo in the second part of your answer, but if you have the hostname from another app, try it with that. Otherwise it might be worth asking for more details from the admin, as psycopg2 needs to know where to connect.